# Prefill information in Core Data at startup.

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I have to do an iOS application that used core data to store the information.

I created the model and how to add data into the application, everything is working perfect, the only problem I have is that, the data model is empty, but I wanted to fill automatically with some data when the application is startup.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at some of the sample apps, like the iPhone [Core Data Books](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html). Basically you ship a pre-filled database with your app, and on initial startup your app delegate copies it into the application's Documents directory, using the data you populated in the database.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the original data file still remains on disk, and consequently takes up unnecessary space after the migration.  Imagine having a large initial data set, say 250Mb, after the "prefill" your app will grow in space usage by at least 250Mb, and the original 250Mb is now redundant, ie it's duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, you can't start with a pre-built data store with Core Data--you'll have to create your store on first run.

Apple's tips and tricks for this initial import can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW1). 98% of the time, it's best to just follow along with their docs.