# iOS Initial Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I want my app to have some initial core data objects in it. Users can delete these objects and on the next start up of the app the objects should still be gone. How can I implement it so only when my app is **installed** it populates the core database with initial values of my choice? That is, I don't want these values to be loaded every time the app launches or starts up; only one time. Is there any method to do this similar to how we creates entities with the graphic interface of xcode?

Comment: This link sounds like it will be helpful: [CoreDataTut](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated)

Comment: I read that but it seemed like it might load the database values when the app starts even in the case where my user previously deleted all the initial values since it uses the app delegate to initialize the loading. Also, I didn't see the method he specific in the app delegate anyhow.

Comment: @user1529956, you obviously did NOT read it... You may have skimmed the first paragraph? I'm going to quote directly from that link to answer your first statement... "This chunk of code checks to see if a sqlite db already exists for this app. If it doesn’t exist, it finds the path for the preloaded sqlite db we loaded and tries to copy the db to the path for the normal app db."

Comment: @Albert Renshaw That is actually the exact line I read that led me to my statement. Perhaps I misunderstood it, particularly the part that says, "...if a sqlite db already exists for this app..." Wouldn't the sqlite db be gone if my user deleted all the objects from it? This may be an error in my understanding of the sqlite db and core data relation.

Comment: @user1529956 Oh, no, it will still be there it will just be empty :)

Comment: @Albert Renshaw oh so is the sqlite db directly related to the UIManagedDocument? That is, if the document exists, then the sqlite db exists?

Comment: @user1529956 Basically you have your default values, and it's copying them over to the actual directory where it's stored, if there is nothing is in that directory than it will copy over your default values, if there is something already there (I.e. it's been copied before) (even if it's an empty file) it will not overwrite it with your default values)

Comment: @Albert Renshaw I see, thanks. I also found this which seems simpler: http://code.google.com/p/coredatalibrary/wiki/LoadingInitialData The problem is, in my directory that I've saving too, instead of an sqlite file, all I have is a folder named "StoreContent" with a file inside called "persistanceStore" (no file extension. any idea what's going on? And also where to find the DataController.m file? Also, any idea about where to find that method the first link mentioned about the app delegate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prefill information in Core Data at startup.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544890/prefill-information-in-core-data-at-startup)

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the data in some other form, e.g. a plist or xml file, and import it on first run, creating the necessary Core Data objects in code and saving to the persistent store. You should also set a `NSUserDefaults` key to record if the app has run already and the items were created successfully.

When the app starts, check for the user defaults key, if it is not there, populate, otherwise don't. Just checking the contents of the persistent store will not be enough because as you pointed out in your question the user might have deleted the seed data.

If you are using iCloud, you should check first if the app has run already on some other device.